# What is the first documented mention of female period loss (amenorrhea)?

Tags: ancient-history, food, health

(Hypothalamic) Amenorrhea is defined as the absence of menstruation during the reproductive years of a woman's life. According to physiologists, it's an evolutionary biological mechanism that gets activated when the living conditions are not lucky for reproduction and childbearing.

Are there any documented mentions or case studies about that in human history?

I'm especially interested in documented cases dating before the 19th century.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Anachronistically framing the question in terms of a modern medical conception makes it difficult. Are you simply asking for the earliest reference to an irregular menstrual cycle? A quick search shows we know about ancient herbal treatments for that. Or are you looking more specifically for an analysis of the cause that is similar to the modern one you describe?

Comment: It's a good question but we don't have many questions about the history of human biology - perhaps history of science or medicine would be a better bet for finding out.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestions, Ne Mo and Brian Z!!

Brian Z, I'm looking for an analysis of the cause described by ancient physicians. But any other references would be really useful too.

Thank you for the note re ancient herbal treatments, I'll research the sources for these, as well as their authors.

Comment: @MilaA Soranus of Ephesus (ca. 100AD -150AD) covered amenorrhea in chapt. 48 of his treatise *Gynaecology*. The Greek text with a Latin translation can be found [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Peri_gynaikei%C5%8Dn_path%C5%8Dn_romanized_form/j7mlwopskRUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=xlviii&pg=PA195&printsec=frontcover). Soranus methodically enumerates many possible causes of the condition, including lack of nutrition / emaciation / wasting ("Reliqui autem corporis vitio veluti cum minime nutritur et multum extenuatur et contabescit") and too much exercise ("quae vocis aliisque exercitationibus")

Comment: Thank you so much for linking the historical reference, njuffa!